# Displaying a text on a view

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

The code below is part of my controller function;

```
success: function (response) {

                            var text = response.responseText;

                            var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

                            var indexPanel = Ext.create('app.view.PersonDetails');

                            Ext.getCmp('mainView').push({

   xtype:'person',

   data: result

   });

}
```

The code below, is the view, which i am passing values from my Controller function (above).
The code below, demonstrates hard coded data in that view (`Hard coded text`), but what i want to do is to display the `data: result` that i am passing from Controller function (above) to be displayed in the following view. How can i do this ?

```
Ext.define('app.view.UserInformation',{

           extend:'Ext.Panel',

           xtype:'person',

           config: {
                title:'Person details',       
    html:['Hard coded text'].join("")
           }

});
```

**UPDATE**

The `result` contains several values like;

`result.name, result.age. result.gender`

I will be passing `result` to the other view.

1.) from the View, how can i add a button ? and wen the user clicks on that button how can i fetch the `result.age` field and do a if condition to check if the age is below 10 ?

2.) Imagine, if there's a field called, `result.imageurl`, how could i display the image on the other view (in a frame) ?

**UPDATE2**

```
Ext.getCmp('mainpanel').push({

 title: 'Hello ' ,
xtype:'person'
});
Ext.getCmp('idOfTheView').setRecord(result.first_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is Sencha Touch alone, not relevant to PhoneGap. :)

Suppose that your view has an id: `view_id`

Then in your controller function:

`Ext.getCmp('view_id').setHtml(what you want to put into your view)`

**Updated answer:**

Your question consists of several sub-questions. I'm afraid that the scope you're asking is too wide but I will answer the most important part.

(from my own application):

```
Ext.define('rs.view.ProductInfo', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'ProductInfo',
    id: 'product-info',
    cls: 'product-info',

    config: {
            items: [
                    {
                            xtype: 'panel',
                            styleHtmlContent: true,
                            id: 'product-info-header',
                            tpl: [
                                    '<div class="product-info-header">',
                                            '<img src={image} width="100px" height="100px"/>',
                                            '<h3>{name}</h3>',
                                            '<h4>Price: {price}</h4>',
                                            '<h4>Seller: {sellerUsername}</h4>',
                                    '</div>',
                            ],
                    },
            ],
    }
});
```

Note that I defined a Model with attributes, `{image},{name},{price},{sellerUsername}`, then in the code snippet above, you can see that I use them in `tpl` config as if normal use in `Ext.List` (with `store` config). So how can I do it?

First, you have to define a model describing your result. obviously.

Second, define `tpl` in your view, I believe you can figure it out from the example above.

Finally, use this (assume that you've written the result received from server into your Model instance which I've mentioned in first step):

`Ext.getCmp('your_view_id').setRecord(your_model_instance)`

100% work warranty because I've used this many times. Hope it helps. Should you have any question, please leave a comment.

Comment: I don't want to do this the way you suggested. I like to pass the `data` from the controller to the View. If so how could do this ?

Comment: 1.) What do you mean by ` I defined a Model with attributes, ` ? I have a folder called `Model` in my sencha touch project and its empty. 2.) What should i say for `your_model_instance` ? is it `result.name` etc..

Comment: I mean you have to define a Model representing your result, with attributes: `name`, `age`, `gender`. When you fetch from server, create an instance of that Model, save all information into it and run `setRecord` as I showed above

Comment: this is a quite complicated but **programmatical** and **best practice** process in Sencha Touch 2. Hope it helps.

Comment: Where should i have the following code `Ext.getCmp('your_view_id').setRecord(result.name)

` ? is it inside the `                            Ext.getCmp('mainView').push({
` according to my code ? Help :(

Comment: yes, right after you've created that model instance containing your necessary results, anh views (of course).

Comment: but, it doesn't work if i put it in `Ext.getCmp('mainView').push({ `any clue ?

Comment: after you've created the view, not inside it :D

Comment: it's a little bit hard to understand at first. But just imagine it's similar to `Ext.List`, you have `store` config, and `itemTpl` config, and decide which attributes of models from `store` are displayed to user. Then, `view`, `tpl`, `model`, `setRecord` are simple.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please have a look.. Is there any tutorial i could follow... :((

Comment: I'm stuck, Could you help me a bit more.. :S

Comment: this is quite difficult to understand for beginners, but come on ... hope these examples help you a little bit. http://senchaexamples.com/2012/03/23/populating-an-ext-form-panel-container-from-a-model-using-sencha-touch-2/ and this http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-3/

Comment: or further, you can post your question and your code snippet to Sencha Touch official forum here. Sorry for my limited timespan so I cannot give a tutorial (which maybe VERY long) ... you may post it here: http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?91-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Discussion good luck! :)